# How to create custom routing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Let say I have Event controller. In the controller, I have 3 actions: attendees, photos, and messages.

How do I achieve the following route schema:

1. www.site.com/event/{eventname}
2. www.site.com/event/{eventname}/action/
3. www.site.com/event/{eventname}/action/{actionid}

Controller will be called EventController, Action can be any of the three actions (attendees, photos, and messages). E.g.

- www.site.com/event/ - list all the events
- www.site.com/event/autiebirthday/ - show auntibirthday event, in this page there will be links to call photos, messages, and attendees action.
- www.site.com/event/autiebirthday/photos/ - list all the photos of auntie birthday event.
- www.site.com/event/autiebirthday/photos/1 - show photo with id 1, along with comments.

Thanks.

Rwendi

Comment: What controller/action should each URL map to?

Comment: Is eventname a parameter that is required to actions?

Comment: added example, hope this clarifies things.

Comment: Yes eventname is a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Route table:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "EventHome", // Route name
        "event/{eventName}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Event", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

Controller:

```
public class EventController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string eventName)
    {
        ViewBag.EventName = eventName;

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Photos(int? id)
    {
        ViewBag.Id = id;

        return View();
    }
}
```

Note that I simply used `ViewBag` in order to test that the routes work.  You should naturally use a proper data source for production.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what the url should call, but i think this should do it

```
routes.MapRoute("", "event/{eventname}", new { controller = "Event", action = "Messages" });
routes.MapRoute("", "event/{eventname}/action/{actionid}", new { controller = "Event", action = "Messages", actionId = UrlParameter.Optional });
```